Accessing swift files in common module of KMM project
I have a KMM project with CMP where i want to provide shared UI to an app that consumes an Android SDK and an iOS SDK (they are native since they handle system sensors and such), their API surface is the same,
I am trying to access a class  OSTUserAttributes in the iosMain folder, however that class seems to be unavailable.
I have created a wrapper for that class.
import Foundation
import OSTSDK // Import the SDK containing OSTUserAttributes

@objc public class KmmUserAttributes: NSObject {
    private var builder: OSTUserAttributes.Builder
    private var userAttributes: OSTUserAttributes?
    
    public override init() {
        self.builder = OSTUserAttributes.Builder()
        super.init()
    }
    
    @objc public func setFirstName(_ name: String) {
        builder = builder.withFirstName(name)
    }
}

And created a bridging header iosApp/iosApp-Bridging-Header.h
#import "iosApp-Swift.h"
#import "KmmUserAttributes.h"

I cleaned, i built, but whatever i do i have not managed to access KmmUserAttributes in iosMain
Is there any other approach for accessing swift files from iosApp in iosMain?
